# iOS 14, Swift UI 2 change background color of selected List item inside a NavigationLink

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-navigationlink

How can I change the background color of a list item while it is selected inside of a `NavigationLink`?

It is always highlighted in blue (see the attached screen). I tried to change the `listRowBackgroundColor` view modifier, but it didn't work.

```
NavigationView {
    
    List (templateModel.model.items) { item in
        
        NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(selectedCategory: item.name, dismiss: dismiss)
            .environmentObject(OrientationInfo())) {
             Text("Test")
                 .listRowBackground(Color.gray)
        }
        .background(Color.black)
        .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
        .listRowBackground(Color.gray)
    }    
    .background(Color.black) 
    .listStyle(InsetListStyle())
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just use `.accentColor`, as below

[image]

```
List (templateModel.model.items) { item in

    // ... other content here

}
.accentColor(.gray)       // << here !!
```